# Trouble Parsing Entire Laravel/Eloquent Collection's JSONB PostgreSQL Table Column

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a PostgreSQL table that stores articles for a simple Laravel CRUD/CMS application.  The PostgreSQL table also has a JsonB column to store each piece of an individual article (title, image url, body/text content, author, etc.).

So on a single article's show page I have no problem parsing the one specific JSONB column and accessing each individual piece of data for that single article, but when it comes to parsing an entire collection of articles from the same table I am wondering what the best way of doing that would be?  I am having trouble doing json_decode on one specific column when using a variable to store an Eloquent query for an entire collection of articles.

I am new to parsing JSON from a data table so I am wondering if there is something built into Laravel/Eloquent that makes accessing one JSON column and parsing it easy for an entire collection from a table?

Here is basically how my PostgreSQL table looks- - only keep in mind that there are several entries not just one, and that is where I am facing the challenge of parsing an entire collection of similarly formatted Eloquent collection objects!

```
|-----------|-----------------------------------------|--------|----------|
|     ID    |  JSONB                                  | Created|  Updated |
|           |                                         | (Date) |   (Date) |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------|--------|----------|
|   1       |  "article": {                           |        |          |
|           |  "title": "Here is a title",            | 2/8/18 |   2/9/18 |
|           |  "image": "image_url.jpg",              |        |          |
|           |  "body": "Lorem ipsum blah blah blah    |        |          |
|           |           more long text blah blah",    |        |          |
|           |  "author": "Edgar Allan Poe",           |        |          |
|           |   "etc": "yeah, you get the idea..?"    |        |          |
|           |             }                           |        |          |       
|           |                                         |        |          |
|-----------|-----------------------------------------|--------|----------|
```

Any help offered is genuinely appreciated, even if this is a duplicated question at this point I would appreciate being pointed in a direction so I can make better progress with my code!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My question is why would you want to store a JSON in a field if you can just create another table or create columns on your current table. This doesn't make sense to me! You are making it so hard to create a robust application if you don't follow the standard database principles.

Nevertheless you could do something like this:

```
$collection = (new YourEntityName())->get();
$collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    $data = json_decode($item->jsonb);
    return is_null($data) []: $data;
});
```

This will return your json in an array. So you can access the data inside the json like:

```
$articles = [];
foreach($collection as $item)
{
    $articles[]= $item->first()->jsonb['article'];
}
dump($articles);
```

Still i think this is something related to your database design but suit yourself!